# The embedded tableau dashboard doesn't render on page refresh in Angular 11

Tags: angular, tableau-api, visualization

I have a tableau online dashboard embedded in the Angular application. I am fetching the viz in ngOnInit() method of the component and storing the return object in a variable so I can render it in the html element.

When a user first navigates to the page using navigation tab, the dashboard is rendered properly.

But when the user refreshes the page, even though the tableau viz is fetched again from tableau online API in  ngOnInit()  method, it is not rendered in the HTML component.

I have tried printing the tableau object in the console on page refresh to see if it is null or not. As expected, it is not null. But the HTML element linked with the object doesn't show any thing.

Could someone point out why is this happening?

Comment: are there any errors showing in the web browser?

Comment: There are no errors. The only difference I could spot between browser refresh and the page navigation is that, on browser refresh **Tableau Shared Widget**   is not loaded.

Comment: Tried that, makes no difference. The tableau dashboard is rendered through an iframe and I am not sure why is the iframe not rendered on browser refresh.